# PureOS on a MSI GS63 w/ GTX 1060

Tags: linux

The hardware requirements to install PureOS states that non-free software will not run on PureOS.  My keyboard is a SteelSeriesRGB, GPU GTX 1060 6GB VR and my fans are controlled with Dragon Center.  Do these qualify as non-free?  Will PureOS generify my hardware?

Comment: Software is not hardware.

Answer (score 0):

PureOS is a GNU/Linux distribution based on Debian. It is a desktop distribution that can be used as live media (CD or USB) or a full-featured operating system installed on a hard disk. Boot from the PureOS live media, and try running PureOS as a live session without installing it on the hard disk to check if it is compatible with your keyboard and GPU and it is able to control your computer's fans properly. Regarding the Nvidia GTX 1060 GPU, PureOS will use the built-in Nouveau open source graphics driver rather than the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver (*nvidia-driver*) from the default Debian repositories.